# InputString in Button freezes Mathematica

Tags: front-end, dynamic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Button[ … , ChoiceDialog[] ] freeze the front end?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5356/why-does-button-choicedialog-freeze-the-front-end)

**Warning: the following code may freeze your session,** as it does mine. I have to wait for the dialog asking whether to abort dynamic updating if that happens. Run this with a fresh kernel:

```
Button["Pressing this button may freeze your session!", 
       InputString["Type something", "(or just press Enter)"]
      ]
```

and press the button. Then try to interact with the dialog. I see a spinning wait cursor, then I have to "Abort" dynamic execution twice to get back control of Mathematica (the kernel quits).

I found no items under "Possible Issues" for either `InputString` or `Button` that could explain this.

1. Is this a bug?
2. How else could I obtain input from a user who clicks a button?

Version 8.0.4 on Mac OSX.