# Why do buttons with ChoiceDialog freeze the front end?

Tags: front-end, dynamic

Pressing the button below will freeze my front end.  An unpainted white dialog box comes up, then it completely freezes, and I need to forcibly kill the front end.  CPU usage stays at zero during this.

```
Button["Ask", If[ChoiceDialog["OK?"], Print["OK!"]]]
```

Why does this happen?

What is the proper way to ask for confirmation before an action?

---

**Answers:**

My first question has been answered below and in the comment by @JohnFultz: use `Button[..., Method -> "Queued"]`.  But this will make a button which doesn't work while evaluations are ongoing.

I need a button which works even during evaluations.  I came up with the following solution:

```
Button["Ask", 
 CreateDialog[
  Column[{"OK?", 
    ChoiceButtons[{"OK"}, {Print["OK!"]; DialogReturn[]}]}]]]
```

`CreateDialog` returns immediately without waiting for an input, so the front end is not blocked.  The functionality is moved completely into the dialog's button.

You can test that the button works and reacts immediately even while `Pause[10]` is evaluating.

---

Quoting the two most enlightening comments:

> The "Preemptive" method interrupts queued (e.g., Shift+Enter)
>   evaluations to do its work and cannot itself be interrupted. I.e., you
>   can't preempt a preemptive calculation. ChoiceDialog is putting up an
>   interface which independently needs the attention of the Mathematica
>   kernel, but can't get it because Button has the kernel's sole
>   attention - [John Fultz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5356/why-do-buttons-with-choicedialog-freeze-the-front-end#comment14628_5357)

> Button[..., Method->"Preemptive"] (the default Method value) and
>   InputString[] are effectively exactly the opposite of each other.
>   Button[..., Method->"Preemptive"] will pause the user interface
>   (causing it to stop responding to events) until the computation is
>   complete. InputString[] will pause the computation until the user has
>   input some value. When you combine these two the user interface is
>   waiting for the computation to complete while at the same time the
>   computation is waiting for user interface input. - [ragfield](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5356/why-do-buttons-with-choicedialog-freeze-the-front-end#comment14617_5352)

Comment: My vague guess is this has to do with evaluating things on the main or preemptive link, but I'm not sure ...

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi Thanks, ragfield's description there is very instructive.

Comment: It's not a bug.  Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885088/why-does-button-choicedialog-freeze-the-front-end).

Comment: Please also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767685/executing-buttonhi-inputstring-causes-instant-frontend-crash#comment8030234_6767780)

Comment: I flagged those two questions to be moved here.  I propose we merge all three (I volunteer to do the editing).

Comment: Please merge and edit as you wish @Szabolcs. Funny, I did a search of the archives and tags, and the mma beta question did not come up. Shall we tag that one with something more descriptive than "untagged"?

Comment: Of course!  Let's just wait for the other question to be migrated as well :-)  The other question is my own, and I also didn't find this when searching SO before I asked it.

Comment: I just bumped into this, and it hasn't got an accepted answer. If you are expecting more, I think I could write up something, but what exactly is the question left to answer?

Comment: @Rojo I don't remember why I didn't accept, now I did.  The most valuable are the comments by ragfield and JF.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following two alternatives, pressing the button while the Do loop is waiting.

```
Button["Click Here", Print[10!], Method -> "Preemptive"]
Do[Print[x]; Pause[5], {2}]
(*
 -> x
 -> 3628800
 -> x
*)
```

and

```
Button["Click Here", Print[10!], Method -> "Queued"]
Do[Print[x]; Pause[5], {2}]
(*
 -> x
 -> x
 -> 3628800
*)
```

**Some Explanation:**

You can see that in the first case, the Do loop is interrupted for processing the Button procedure, but in the second case it is just queued and the Button processing is postponed until the Do loop ends.

In the case of the "Preemptive" method, Mma wants to assure that you are not stealing the CPU forever and impeding the Do loop finalization, so it gives you a certain time slice to process the Button procedure. If you yield control to human input (as in InputString[]), that time slice expires and thus the results you are getting.

Answer (score 13):

Try `Method-> "Queued"`. This works for me, although I cannot say just why.

```
Button["Ask", If[ChoiceDialog["OK?"], Print["OK!"]], Method -> "Queued"]
```

Here's the explanation from the docs:

[image]

Comment: The "Preemptive" method interrupts queued (e.g., Shift+Enter) evaluations to do its work and cannot itself be interrupted.  I.e., you can't preempt a preemptive calculation.  `ChoiceDialog` is putting up an interface which independently needs the attention of the Mathematica kernel, but can't get it because `Button` has the kernel's sole attention.

Comment: @John Fultz Thanks. That now makes sense.

Comment: I'm also wondering if there's a way to "unfreeze" the front end if this happens ...

Comment: @Szabolcs Every time the front end froze and I called up `Force Quit` (on my Mac), a dialogue box from mma popped up asking me if I wanted to abort the evaluation.  Then aborting worked.  This may have been a mere coincidence but it happened 5 or 6 times.

Answer (score 7):

For this, you need to use Method->"Queued"

```
Button["hi", InputString[], Method -> "Queued"]
```

Comment: Thanks! Interesting. I can't say I know enough of the inner-workings of Mathematica to understand why the hang-up occurs, although I just went into Documentation Center and saw that it crops up under "Possible Issues".

Comment: Button[..., Method->"Preemptive"] (the default Method value) and InputString[] are effectively exactly the opposite of each other.  Button[..., Method->"Preemptive"] will pause the user interface (causing it to stop responding to events) until the computation is complete.  InputString[] will pause the computation until the user has input some value.  When you combine these two the user interface is waiting for the computation to complete while at the same time the computation is waiting for user interface input.