# ClickPane that shows or hides controls when clicked

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

I am trying to modify the parameters of a system by clicking on its graphics. I am using `ClickPane` with `DialogInput`. A code example is as follows.

```
DynamicModule[{},
 ClickPane[
  Framed[Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]], 
  (If[Norm[#] < 1, DialogInput[Grid[{{CancelButton[], DefaultButton[DialogReturn[1]]}}]]];) &
 ]
]
```

As expected, the `Dialog` window appears with a click in the red circle. However, it takes a long time before it is enabled. I am new with `Dynamic` modules. Could someone explain the reason of this?

Comment: That's because it uses Preemptive link. You need a controller with Method->"Queued" to prompt a dialog, which is a Button or an ActionMenu.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Here's more info, take a look at John Fultz's comment too [5357](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5357/5478)

Answer (score 3):

I can not get a click pane to play nice with an input dialog. I offer the following as a work-around that suggests another way for you to accomplish your goal.

```
DynamicModule[{grid, color = Red, r = 1., controls = ""},
  grid =
    Grid[{
      {Style["Color", "SR"], RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[color], {Red, Green, Blue}]},
      {Style["Radius", "SR"], RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[r], {1., 1.5}]}}];
  Column[{
    ClickPane[
      Framed[
        Dynamic @
          Graphics[{color, Disk[{0, 0}, r]}, 
            PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}},
            ImageSize -> Medium]],
      If[Norm[#] < r, controls = grid, controls = ""] &],
    Dynamic @ controls},
    Center]]
```

When the above code is evaluated, the output cell it generates looks like this

[image: initial-disk]

After clicking inside the disk, the controls become visible, and the disk can be adjusted and be made to look this.

[image: disk-with-controls]

Clicking outside the disk hides the controls.

I chose radio button bars for the controls in this example, but any controls can be put in the control grid.

Comment: @Karsten7. From [`DialogInput`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DialogInput.html) under Possible Issues: "DialogInput blocks the queued evaluation channel, preventing queued controls from working".

Comment: @Karsten7. I made the change you suggested concerning `Norm[#] < r`. Good catch.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I modified your code in my answer to have the controls switch on or off by the `DialogInput`.

Answer (score 1):

A modification of [the code in the anwer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97579/18476) by [m_goldberg](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3066/m-goldberg), that uses `DialogInput` to switch the controls on and off:

```
DynamicModule[{grid, color = Red, r = 1., controls = ""}, 
 grid = Grid[{{Style["Color", "SR"], 
     RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[color], {Red, Green, Blue}]}, {Style[
      "Radius", "SR"], RadioButtonBar[Dynamic[r], {1., 1.5}]}}];
 Column[{Dynamic@
    ClickPane[
     Framed[Graphics[{color, Disk[{0, 0}, r]}, 
       PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, ImageSize -> Medium]], 
     If[Norm[#] < r, 
       controls = 
        DialogInput[
         Grid[{{CancelButton[DialogReturn[""]], 
            DefaultButton[DialogReturn[grid]]}}]], controls = ""] &, 
     Method -> "Queued"], Dynamic@controls}, Center]]
```

Comment: good finding, ClickPane now does have the Method option as well, although not yet documented. That of course solves the OPs problem in the most straightforward way...

Comment: just for completeness: the `Method` option for `ClickPane` seems to be new for version 10.2, in all older versions it isn't listed in the `Options`, and it also doesn't seem to work for those...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Thanks for pointing that out. I wasn't aware of that. *Mathematica* v9 got messed up, as I just tried to run my code.

Answer (score 1):

As others have explained the trick to get this working with a modal dialog is to not use the preemptive but the queued method. The easiest way to achieve this is to just use a button which doesn't look like one. Here is a straightforward translation of your `ClickPane` example:

```
Button[
   Framed[Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}]], 
     Function[If[Norm[#] < 1, 
       DialogInput[
         Grid[{{#, SpanFromLeft}, {CancelButton[], 
         DefaultButton[DialogReturn[1]]}}]]];
     ][MousePosition["Graphics"]],
  Method -> "Queued",
  Appearance -> None
]
```

but for what you describe as your actual goal it would be even easier to use a button for the object you want to change directly:

```
Framed[Graphics[{
  Red,
  Button[
    Disk[{0, 0}, 1], 
    DialogInput[
      Grid[{{CancelButton[], DefaultButton[DialogReturn[1]]}}]], 
      Method -> "Queued",
      Appearance -> None
    ]
  },
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}
]]
```

Comment: The first way works well. The second way is still slow. Is this related to using Mac OS?

Comment: @ChristianMullon: it might be Mac OS but it also could be the Mathematica version you are using. I tried this with Mathematica 10.2 on Windows 7 and it does not run into the timeout as the clickplane version does...

Comment: As Karsten found Clickpane does itself have a `Method->"Queued"` option which I think is the most simple and probably best to use for your example...