# Why doesn't Button work with loop?

Tags: dynamic, button

It seems that I cannot use a loop in Dynamic. Quite ridiculous??

Here is my minimal example:

```
Grid[{{Button["test", i = 0; While[i < 10, Pause[10]; i++]], InputField[Dynamic[i]]}}]
```

I expect the dynamic i will increase by one every ten seconds(10 seconds gap is set to prevent it goes too fast to be observed). But the truth is i just starts from 0 and stops when I click on the button.

Thanks for your attention! Any comments and suggestion will be very welcome.

**Edit:**
Thanks to comments from Kuba, I am now able to let the button update the value of i in a loop, but it still fails to work if I put them in DynamicsModule after check some other related questions.

The minimal example is:

```
DynamicModule[{i = 0},  Grid[{{Button["test", i = 0; 
 While[i < 10, i++; Pause[1]; FinishDynamic[]], 
 Method -> "Queued"], 
InputField[Dynamic[i, UpdateInterval -> .5]]}}]]
```

Comment: This will work: `Button["test", i = 0; While[i < 10, Pause[1]; i++; FinishDynamic[]],  Method -> "Queued"]`. `Method` is a must and `FinishDynamic[]` is a remedy for this bug: [100828](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100828/5478)

Comment: Do you mean this 'feature' is a known bug in Mathematica 11.1? @ Kuba♦

Comment: The point is that preemptive evaluation locks the front end so InputField won't be updated before whole loop finishes.

Comment: Thanks! I see it now. Because 'Button' will time out after 5 seconds by default. What a hidden pitfall!

Comment: further reading: [59949](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59949/5478),  [5356](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5356/5478)

Comment: Let me know if anything is not covered in linked topics